# can't get notification from expo notification after build apk

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, expo-notifications

I am currently working on a React Native Expo application, and I'm trying to use Expo Notifications. It works well on Expo Go, but after building the APK, I can't receive any notifications. Can anyone help me?
this is my app.js code :

```
import "react-native-gesture-handler";
import { StatusBar, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import Stacks from "./src/Routes/Stacks";
import { I18nManager } from "react-native";
import NoConnectionScreen from "./src/Seller Screens/Screens/NoConnectionScreen";
import { useNetInfo } from "@react-native-community/netinfo";
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import * as Device from "expo-device";
import * as Notifications from "expo-notifications";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";
Notifications.setNotificationHandler({
  handleNotification: async () => ({
    shouldShowAlert: true,
    shouldPlaySound: true,
    shouldSetBadge: false,
  }),
});
try {
  I18nManager.allowRTL(false);
  I18nManager.forceRTL(false);
  // the next line is the most effective one
  I18nManager.swapLeftAndRightInRTL(false);
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e);
}
const App = () => {
  state = { rtl: false };
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const notificationListener = useRef();
  const responseListener = useRef();
  async function registerForPushNotificationsAsync() {
    let token;

    if (Platform.OS === "android") {
      await Notifications.setNotificationChannelAsync("default", {
        name: "default",
        importance: Notifications.AndroidImportance.MAX,
        vibrationPattern: [0, 250, 250, 250],
        lightColor: "#FF231F7C",
      });
    }

    if (Device.isDevice) {
      const { status: existingStatus } =
        await Notifications.getPermissionsAsync();
      let finalStatus = existingStatus;
      if (existingStatus !== "granted") {
        const { status } = await Notifications.requestPermissionsAsync();
        finalStatus = status;
      }
      if (finalStatus !== "granted") {
        alert("Failed to get push token for push notification!");
        return;
      }
      token = await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync({
        projectId: "b37ba3bc-286c-43a3-b3f2-ae2fa40ca6cd",
      });
      const expotoken = token.data;
      console.log(token.data);
      await AsyncStorage.setItem("expotoken", expotoken);
    } else {
      alert("Must use physical device for Push Notifications");
    }

    return token;
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    registerForPushNotificationsAsync();
    notificationListener.current =
      Notifications.addNotificationReceivedListener((notification) => {
        console.log(notification);
      });

    responseListener.current =
      Notifications.addNotificationResponseReceivedListener((response) => {
        console.log(response);
      });

    return () => {
      Notifications.removeNotificationSubscription(
        notificationListener.current
      );
      Notifications.removeNotificationSubscription(responseListener.current);
    };
  }, []);
  setTimeout(() => {
    setIsLoading(false);
  }, 20);
  const net = useNetInfo();

  return (
    <>
      <StatusBar backgroundColor={"#6c757d"} barStyle="light-content" />
      {net.isConnected == true && isLoading == false && <Stacks />}
      {net.isConnected == false && <NoConnectionScreen />}
    </>
  );
};
export default App;
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
});
```

tried
useNextNotificationsApi:true
and this
expo push:android:upload --api-key